# Weak convergence of measure defined on Lebesgue measurable sets.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Let $f_j \in L^1 (\mathbb{R}^n)$, $f_j\ge 0$ for all $j=0,1,\ldots$, be such that $f_j \to f_0$ in $L^1 (\mathbb{R}^n)$. The measure is defined for Lebesgue measurable sets $A \in \mathbb{R}^n$ by 
$$
\mu_j (A) = \int_A f_j \, dm_n.
$$
Show that $\mu_j \to \mu_0$.

We define the weak convergence for every continuous function $g$ with compact support, that
$$
\lim_{j \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} g \,d\mu_j = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} g \,d\mu_0. 
$$

My attempt: I take a $g\in C_0 (\mathbb{R}^n) $ and estimate it $| g |\le \| g\|_\infty < \infty$ and denote $\mathrm{supp}(g) = A$ (it's compact). Then use the estimate further to use the convergence: $f_j \to f_0$ in $L^1 (\mathbb{R}^n)$. Propably the form of $\mu_j$ boggles me. Is this correct, if not, how should I begin to prove this? Hints are most welcome.

Comment: Do you know how $\int g \,d\mu_j$ can be expressed in terms of $f_j$?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't. It might have been shown in lectures, but I havent been able to attend lately. Perhaps that is why I am struggling in this problem. How is it expressed?

Comment: You have $\int g d\mu_j = \int gf_j dm$.

Comment: Oh! How do you derive that? A simple explanation would be helpful or a short proof for that!

Comment: If $g$ is a characteristic function it's just the definition. So it's true if $g$ is simple by linearity. Now appproximate $g$ by simple functions in a suitable way and apply dominated convergence.

Comment: I can see how that goes. Thank you all.